# Crayfish 3.0.0 not working in QGIS 3.4.3

Tags: qgis, installation

I tried to install Crayfish 3.0 in QGIS 3.4 and although I didn't get any errors during the installation of the plugin I don't have access to all Crayfish features. I can only use the 'plot' and 'export animations' features but I don't have the option to load xmdf files or .dat or use any other crayfish tools.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/159553)

Comment: No, I couldn't so I gave up. I am using an older version of QGIS with Crayfish.

Answer (score 0):

QGIS 3.4 introduced MDAL allowing the user to read TUFLOW results directly in to QGIS without a plugin. To add TUFLOW results, first add a mesh (.2dm) file as a Mesh layer using the Data Source Manager. Right click on the loaded mesh layer in the layers panel and open the properties window. On the source tab, click "Assign Extra Dataset to Mesh" and navigate to the TUFLOW results you wish to associate with this mesh (e.g. .dat / .xmdf). After a few seconds, the results are now loaded and ready to use with the Crayfish and TUFLOW plugins.

Source > https://www.tuflow.com/forum/index.php?/topic/1749-qgis-34-and-tuflow-results/

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_mesh/mesh_properties.html#